# Redirect Users After Registration to Their Author Posts URL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

I need to redirect user after registration to their author page.

The filter `'registration_redirect'` is working, I just can't seem to retrieve the recently registered user ID in order to get their author page and redirect them.

I am trying to get the recently registered user ID from `$_POST`, `wp_get_current_user()`, `$_GET`, however, no luck.

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'redirect_to_author_page' );
function redirect_to_author_page( $registration_redirect ) {
    
    // this is not working
    $user = wp_get_current_user(); 
    $user_id = $user->ID; // EMPTY
    
    // this is not working either
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $_POST['user_email'] ); 
    $user_id = $user->ID; // EMPTY

    $author_url = get_author_posts_url( $user_id );

    return $author_url;
    
}
```

Any idea how could I retrieve the recently registered user ID in the 'registration_redirect' filter?
Any other way I could accomplish this? (Other filter or hook perhaps)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative hook to use is [register_new_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_new_user) as its specific to the `wp-login.php` form and receives the newly registered `$user_id`, eg:

```php
function redirect_to_author_page($user_id)
{
    wp_safe_redirect(get_author_posts_url($user_id));
    exit();
}

add_action('register_new_user', 'redirect_to_author_page');
```

Even though [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/registration_redirect/#parameters) for `registration_redirect` states it should return `$user_id` on success, I tested and found it still contains `WP_Error` in WP 6.3 when called after a successful registration.

Using `register_new_user` won't interfere with the forms error handling; the redirection only occurs after a new user is successfully registered.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation's page for the [registration_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/registration_redirect/) filter, you'll notice a second parameter called $errors.

It's not evident by its name, but, if the registration was successful, this parameter contains the user ID.

So your code should look like this:

```php
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'redirect_to_author_page', 99, 2 );
function redirect_to_author_page( $registration_redirect, $errors ) {
    // Use the default value if the registration wasn't successful
    if ( is_wp_error( $errors ) || ! isset( $errors ) ) {
        return $registration_redirect;
    }

    $user_id = $errors;

    $author_url = get_author_posts_url( $user_id );

    return $author_url;
}
```

Comment: It looks like it should work, however, the `registration_redirect` filter is not bringing any values neither for the $url or the $errors. Moreover, it looks like the `registration_redirect` filter is not being fired at all upon successful registration. I am working on the default wordpress registration such as: `mysite.com/wp-login.php?action=register` ... Any thought why it would not be firing please? Might I be using the wrong filter?